# BigQuery array intersection across all rows

Tags: google-bigquery, set-intersection

I have the following data:

| col1 |
| --- |
| `[1,2,3]` |
| `[1,2]` |
| `[2,3]` |

I want the following output

| ans |
| --- |
| `[2]` |

In other words, I want the intersection of arrays in all rows.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select array_agg(item) ans from (
  select distinct item
  from your_table t, t.col1 item
  qualify count(distinct format('%t', col1)) over(partition by item) 
    = count(distinct format('%t', col1)) over()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be seen below. This is assuming that your arrays does not have duplicate values.

`cte` groups by array value, and gets all the indices that contain this value and counts them. It also assigns row_number for each row. This can now be filtered where the maximum row_number = count of indices that contain the value.

```sql
with sample_data as (
    select [1,2,3] as col1
    union all select [1,2] as col1
    union all select [2,3] as col1
),
cte as (
select 
  col1[safe_offset(index)] as arr_value,
  array_length(array_agg(index)) as exist_in_n_rows, -- get indices where values appeared then count them
  row_number() over () as rn
from sample_data,
  unnest(generate_array(0,array_length(col1)-1)) as index
group by 1
)
select 
array_agg(intersection) as ans
from (
  select 
    arr_value as intersection,
  from cte
    where true
    qualify max(rn) over () = exist_in_n_rows
)
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: If you have duplicate values in the array, it is much better to de duplicate them first prior to running the query above.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection of array of all rows. There is the need to unnest the array and group by each element and count how often it is in a row present.

Lets start with generating your datset in table `tbl`.

Then in a `helper` table, we generate a row_number, starting with one for each row. We also count the maximum numbers of rows.

In the last step, we unnest the `col1` column with all the array elements and call them `y`. We group by `y` and count for each unique entry of `row_num` in the new column `ref`. `having` does a comparing of the `ref` to the total amount of rows in the beginning and filters only the element which are present in all arrays.

```sql
With tbl as (select a.x as col1 from unnest( [struct([1,2,3,3] as x),struct([1,2]),struct([2,3])] )as a),
helper as ( select col1,row_number() over () as row_num,count(col1) over () as counts  from tbl)
select y,count(distinct row_num) as ref, any_value(counts) ref_target  
from helper , unnest(col1) y 
group by 1
having ref=ref_target
```